# Check for any of the property is null

Tags: c#, xml

I am deserializing an XML to a class model and I want to check if there are any  XML nodes that are not deserialized correctly.

My class looks like this:

```
class A
{
    public A1 pop1;
    public A2 prop2;

    // like so n number of classes
}
class  A1
{
    public string Item1{get;set;}
    public string Item2{get;set;}
    public string Item3{get;set;}

    // like so n number of classes
}

class A2
{
    public string Item1{get;set;}
    public string Item2{get;set;}
    public string Item3{get;set;}

    // like so n number of classes
}
```

Is there a way to check if any of objects `A1`, `A2`, etc is `null` and any of the properties inside the object are null or empty? If this is true then deserialization failed.

Answer (score 4):

You could use reflection to walk over the classes and their values.

What I would do in this case though is to make a custom method called `Validate` in an interface `IValidateable`. Let every class implement that interface and write a method to do the validation inside. This makes it easier to deviate from the 'all properties can't be null' rule you have now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [something like this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/70356/47834)

```
public bool HasAllEmptyProperties()
{
    var type = GetType();
    var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var hasProperty = properties.Select(x => x.GetValue(this, null))
                                .Any(y => y != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y.ToString()));
    return !hasProperty;
}
```

I could also have used the All() method and positive comparison instead of Any(). But this is inefficient as all elements have to be checked against the condition whereas Any() will return as soon as an element satisfies the condition